# Change Holo theme progress bar color only

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to change the default progress bar color of android Holo theme and keep the default behavior.

My goal is to keep the progress bar as is (keep all default behavior) and only change its color to purple.
I want to change both horizontal and indeterminate.

this is what I've done so far:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(#b845b2, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(#b845b2,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

this is working except for a small side effect, it changes the secondary progress bar to light purple while the default progress bar is grey, and I want it to be grey as default.

those are the default colors
[image: this is the default colors]
this is what I've achieved so far, but I want the light purple from right to be grey as the first picture
[image: this is what I've achieved so far, but I want the light purple from right to be grey as the first picture]

please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do so with color filters since everything is painted.

You'll need to set the proper images. You can generate them with this tool : [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/). It will also put light purple on the right part but you can edit the images files to put the grey.

If you use that tool, it will create the 9patch images and the stuff you need to put in your theme xml file.

Comment: thanks!, so you saying that color filter is painting the whole progress bar?

Comment: what I should do? after creating the grey 9patch, set it on drawable as secondery progress, and set that drawable as android:progressDrawable=".." in the progress bar layout? in that case I'm loosing the default progress bar behavior? how to preserve it? or I have to rewrite it?

Comment: Use Android Holo Colors, you'll see everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

On newer devices you can also define this in your theme (styles.xml):

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/purple</item>
```